# I want to move the value to next page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and i add one extra colum in grid in this colum i add the link now i want to move the value of question id in which row link exist i move to another page can anyone help me
In form tag i use this code
                             [This is the grid which which i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krPD9.png)

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"   AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle">
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "250px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle"  DataField = "Question_Question"  HeaderText = "Question"/>

        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width ="250" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle" DataField = "Question_Answer" HeaderText = "Answer"/>
       <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width ="100" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle"



    DataField = "Question_Keywords" HeaderText = "KeyWord"/>

        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width ="100" HeaderStyle-Cssclass="HeaderStyle" 
DataField = "Question_Total_Marks" HeaderText = "Total Marks"/>  
             <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width ="100"  HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle">
                      <ItemTemplate>

                          <a href="Teacher_Edit_Paper.aspx">Edit</a>
                           </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width ="100"  HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <a href="#">Delete</a>
                           </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

On selectedindexchange i call this function but this is not work.Iwant to get the id of question in which row edit exist please sir give me the solution.

Comment: You can save it in viewstate or session.

Comment: Farrukh, did you try <asp:HyperlinkField> ?

Comment: <asp:hyperlinkfield headertext="NewsHeadline"
      datatextfield="Title"
      datanavigateurlfield="YourID" 
      datanavigateurlformatstring="http://{0}" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query Parameters Or Session like

**QueryString**

```
<asp:hyperlink id = "hyp" navigateurl ="helloworld.com/id=1"></asp:hyperlink>
```

In other page

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

**For Session**

```
Session["id"] = id.ToString();
```

In other page

```
String id = Session["id"].ToString();
```